# Issue reading RFID tags with MFRC522 and RPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am using RPi 3 B+ and MFRC522 reader. When I run the following code:

https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python/blob/master/Read.py

In the terminal I get endless "Card detected" lines (line 55).

It seems like the next condition:

```
# Get the UID of the card
(status,uid) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll()

# If we have the UID, continue
if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
```

Never passes. Do you know what might be the trouble? (The cards and the readers are compatible 100%)

Can it be a clock issue? How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It was a freaking hardware issue. I dont understand how it detected a card but did not read, I try with another reader and it worked. Sorry for the trouble.